# Docker rails mysql is not connecting

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect my rails app which is on my host to docker mysql image. But I am getting this error:

```
 Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.22/lib/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so, 2): image not found
```

My Docker compose file is like this:

```
db:
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password


adminer:
  image: adminer
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

I am using this inside my database.yml:

```
default: &default
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
host: 127.0.0.1
username: root
password: password
pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
# socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
   database: meal_plan_development
```

What else I should do in order to connect my rails app to mysql docker image.

Comment: I think the MySQL server is requiring an authentication method you don't have installed on your local machine (where I assume rails is running). So you can either try to update your mysql-client libraries (which can be hard) or you can change the authentication method on the mysql server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892720/authentication-plugin-error-while-connecting-to-mysql-database - you could also downgrade the MySQL-image you're using by changing `image: mysql` to `image: mysql:5.7` in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 6):

## MySQL default-authentication-plugin

as of version 8, MySQL uses `caching_sha2_password` as the default authentication plugin. You can override it to use `mysql_native_password` by adding a `command` instruction in your `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```
db:
   image: mysql
   command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
   restart: always
   ports:
      - "3306:3306"
   environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
```

Comment: I had to wipe out the volume from the first time I started the db container because the user was created with the new authentication plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As @vstm pointed out, this seems to be the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50899861/3556378) I was having with a PHP client. After the container has been created you could try changing the authentication scheme to one which will likely be supported e.g.

```
docker exec <container_id> /bin/sh -c "mysql -uroot -ppassword 
-e ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD'"
```

I'm not overly familiar with Docker, but I believe you can also add something like this to a Dockerfile so that the authentication method will be changed during the container initialization:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "mysql -uroot -ppassword 
    -e ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD'"
```